Question regarding terms with negative coefficients in multivariate Fox H function
I was studying a paper where an integral expression in terms of Fox H function of multiple variable were used. The definition of multivariate Fox H (extracted from appendix A-1 of Mathai-Saxena) is as follow
$$H[z_1,\cdots,z_r] = H^{0,n:m_1,n_1;\cdots;m_r,n_r}_{p,q:p_1,q_1;\cdots;p_r,q_r}\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
  &z_1\\
  &\vdots\\
  &z_r
 \end{smallmatrix}\Bigg|\begin{smallmatrix}
    &(a_j;\alpha_j^{(1)},\cdots,\alpha_j^{(r)})_{1,p}:(c_j^{(1)},\gamma_j^{(1)})_{1,p_1};\cdots;(c_j^{(r)},\gamma_j^{(r)})_{1,p_r}\\
    &(b_j;\beta_j^{(1)},\cdots,\beta_j^{(r)})_{1,q}:(d_j^{(1)},\delta_j^{(1)})_{1,q_1};\cdots;(d_j^{(r)},\delta_j^{(r)})_{1,q_r}
    \end{smallmatrix}\right] \\
= \frac{1}{(2\pi w)^r}\int_{L_1}\cdots\int_{L_r}\Psi(\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_r)\left[\prod_{i=1}^{r}\phi_i(\xi_i)z_i^{\xi_i}\right]d\xi_1\cdots d\xi_r$$
where $w = (-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$
$$\Psi(\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_r) = \frac{\prod_{j=1}^{n}\Gamma\left(1-a_j+\sum_{i=1}^{r}\alpha_i^{(i)}\xi_i\right)}{\left[\prod_{j=n+1}^{p}\Gamma\left(a_j-\sum_{i=1}^{r}\alpha_j^{(i)}\xi_i\right)\right]\left[\prod_{j=1}^{q}\Gamma\left(1-b_j+\sum_{i=1}^{r}\beta_j^{(i)}\xi_i\right)\right]}\\
\phi_i(\xi_i) = \frac{\left[\prod_{\lambda=1}^{m_i}\Gamma\left(d_\lambda^{(i)}-\delta_\lambda^{(i)}\xi_i\right)\right]\left[\prod_{j=1}^{n_i}\Gamma\left(1-c_j^{(i)}+\gamma_j^{(i)}\xi_i\right)\right]}{\left[\prod_{j=n_i+1}^{p_i}\Gamma\left(c_j^{(i)}-\gamma_j^{(i)}\xi_i\right)\right]\left[\prod_{\lambda=m_i+1}^{q_i}\Gamma\left(1-d_\lambda^{(i)}+\delta_\lambda^{(i)}\xi_i\right)\right]}$$
There in paper the authors have argued that a certain integral can not be expressed in terms of multivariate Fox-H because the numerator of $\Psi$ does not permit terms with negative coefficients of $\xi_i$, for example there is no terms of the form $\prod_{j=1}^{n}\Gamma\left(b_j-\sum_{i=1}^{r}\beta_i^{(i)}\xi_i\right)$ in the numerator of $\Psi$. Here is my questions
1- Why there is no terms with negative coefficients of $\xi$ in the numerator of $\Psi$? There were no explanations in the appendix of the book mentioned above.
2- Is there a way to handle such terms if appear in the function? Can they be expressed in terms of multivariate Fox-H function
Thank you!
